# unable to display response body using rest template

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, response

see i m havving Register class which contains pojo .

```
public class Register {
private String userFirstName,userLastName;
//getters and setters for this

}
```

this is my service

```
public String Register(Register reg) {
String url = "some URL" ;

        String firstname = reg.getUserFirstName();
        String lastname = reg.getUserLastName();
        JSONObject jsondata = new JSONObject();
        jsondata.put("userFirstName", firstname);
        jsondata.put("userLastName", lastname);
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new Connection().getConnection(jsondata
                .toString());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(
                new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        ResponseEntity<Register> respone;
        try {
        respone = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                Register.class);

         System.out.println("response"+respone.getBody());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("++++++++++++ failed +++++++++++++"+e.getMessage());

        }
```

here in the respone i m getting the response in the form of

```
com.somname.model.Register@67636097
```

but i want to display the response in json form.why i am getting like this..?how can i get the response body..?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that everything works as expected. I am not very familiar with rest templates but I assume it should help you to "hide" REST internals (e.g. JSON coding/decoding).

If you check the Java type of `respone.getBody()` you will get `Register`, thus `println` will produce standard Java `toString()` output as you can see now. So if you want to use it, check fields, but as such it is good that you get as a result as normal Java object.

If for any purposes you want to see JSON (don't know why), you can "manually" convert Java object to JSON using e.g. Jackson library... see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) for details

Comment: but can u tell me why i m getting that type of response,should i use string.class for that?

Comment: you program it that way (see `Register.class` param). But seriously, that's the purpose of rest template to abstract you from JSON representation. This is from javadoc: `It handles HTTP connections, leaving application code to provide URLs (with possible template variables) and extract results.` If you want to get JSON, you can directly use any HTTP client. Can you tell me why do you want to see JSON? Or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @sodik..actually in the response i m getting userid which i want to use in other code.thats why i want that response in json form.i m saving that userid as pojo  in register class

Comment: then you can either use directly HTTP client and parse JSON using e.g. Jackson or model your "transfer objects" to reflect whole JSON response and then convert it to your business objects at your will.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this if this is the name of your getter method for userFirstName, you do the same for userLastName

```
System.out.println("response"+respone.getBody().getUserFirstName());
```